# IBM Sort - Printing a record counter in a Detail Register

Tags: sorting, jcl

I've this file:

```
SORTIN01 DD *
AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEE
```

I'd like use sort to produce a SORTOUT file like this:

```
SORTOUT DD *
AAAAAAAA00000000010000000005
BBBBBBBB00000000020000000005
CCCCCCCC00000000030000000005
DDDDDDDD00000000040000000005
EEEEEEEE00000000050000000005
```

The first 08 bytes are the content of the input file, the next 10 bytes are a sequential number starting in 1 and incremented from 1 by 1, and the last 10 bytes are the total count of the registers in a file.
I know how to count the total of the registers using sort in a trailer of a file, but I don't know how to count the total count registers in a detail register.

I appreciate if anyone knows how to help me.

Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity, why tag websphere?

Comment: What do you mean by 'register' and 'detail register'? Which sort product are you using? There are tags for DFsort and Syncsort. The JCL tag is irrelevant as you are not asking about JCL statements but sort statements. And, presumably, this is on a mainframe for which a tag is available.

Comment: What have you tried ???. You can use `sort OUTREC` statement can be used to reformat the output. Try Googling `sort outrec` and also see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.icea100/outcst.htm